# Ruby on Rails - after_validation if valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Right now, from what I know, `after_validation` will be called even if the model fails the validations. Is there a way to only call it if the model is valid? I tried adding `return false unless self.valid?` in the `after_validation` method but that triggers validation again and it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, you could check for `errors`, like `return false unless self.errors.empty?` or `return false if errors.any?`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The failing validations add to the errors for the record, so you could just check:

```
return false unless self.errors.empty?
```

Comment: I have tried this before and it still failed. Then I checked the code and I noticed that I was calling the validation again (when I wasn't supposed to). Now it works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought about using the `before_save` callback instead?

I believe that will only be called if the object is valid.

Comment: What if I don't want to save it? Just want to validate it?

Comment: You also can't do more advanced things in `before_save` like checking what fields changed in an association (via `xxx_changed?`) since the associations get updated first, thereby resetting the `changed` hash.  As such, it's necessary to perform these checks in `after_validation` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I ran into the same error when using a custom validation on a model I had created. Looking at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) there's a part covering custom methods and it states that such validations are called each time the `.valid?` method. That's probably why the infinite loop got triggered when the `:after_validation` callback was triggered.